# Remove rows with datetime columns not within other datetime columns

Tags: r, data.table, dplyr, reshape2

I have 2 dataframes like this

```
    ID <- c("A","A")
    StartDatetime <- c("2015-09-29 00:00:13", "2015-09-29 05:55:50")
    EndDatetime <- c("2015-09-29 00:13:56", "2015-09-29 06:13:50")
    Measurement <- c("Length","Length")
    df1 <- data.frame(ID,StartDatetime,EndDatetime,Measurement)

    ID <- c("A","A")
    MStart <- c("09/29/2015 00:02:13", "09/29/2015 05:56:50") 
    MEnd <- c("09/29/2015 00:11:12", "09/29/2015 06:55:50") 
    Measurement <- c("Length","Length")
    df2 <- data.frame(ID,MStart,MEnd,Measurement)
```

With the help of users at SO, I was able to format the date time columns like this

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
df1$StartDatetime <- ymd_hms(df1$StartDatetime)
df1$EndDatetime <- ymd_hms(df1$EndDatetime)
df2$MStart<- mdy_hms(df2$MStart)
df2$MEnd<- mdy_hms(df2$MEnd)
```

I am trying to merge these two dataframes using

```
df <- merge(df1,df2,by = c("ID","Measurement"))
```

The problem is that it returns 4 rows

```
  ID Measurement       StartDatetime         EndDatetime              MStart                MEnd
1  A      Length 2015-09-29 00:00:13 2015-09-29 00:13:56 2015-09-29 00:02:13 2015-09-29 00:11:12
2  A      Length 2015-09-29 00:00:13 2015-09-29 00:13:56 2015-09-29 05:56:50 2015-09-29 06:55:50
3  A      Length 2015-09-29 05:55:50 2015-09-29 06:13:50 2015-09-29 00:02:13 2015-09-29 00:11:12
4  A      Length 2015-09-29 05:55:50 2015-09-29 06:13:50 2015-09-29 05:56:50 2015-09-29 06:55:50
```

I would only want to see row 1 & 4 because my MStart should be within StartDatetime & EndDatetime and hence need to remove rows 2,3.

**My desired output is**

```
  ID Measurement       StartDatetime         EndDatetime              MStart                MEnd
1  A      Length 2015-09-29 00:00:13 2015-09-29 00:13:56 2015-09-29 00:02:13 2015-09-29 00:11:12
2  A      Length 2015-09-29 05:55:50 2015-09-29 06:13:50 2015-09-29 05:56:50 2015-09-29 06:55:50
```

How can I filter it? Kindly provide your suggestions.

**EDIT** - I tried foverlaps as eddi suggested and threw an error.

```
    colnames(df2)[2] <- "StartDatetime"
    colnames(df2)[3] <- "EndDatetime"

    y1 = data.table(df1)
    x1 = data.table(df2)
    setkey(y1, StartDatetime, EndDatetime)
    foverlaps(x, y, type="within") ## matches iff 'x' is within 'y'
```

I get the error

```
Error in setkeyv(x, cols, verbose = verbose, physical = physical) : 
  4 arguments passed to .Internal(nchar) which requires 3
```

Comment: How far apart can MStart and StartDatetime be?

Comment: I just modified the question. My MStart should be within StartDatetime & EndDatetime

Comment: `?data.table::foverlaps`

Comment: I tried foverlaps as you suggested and I get an error. Please check my edited part in the question above

Comment: I don't understand what do you want to achieve.  The way you merge your data does not make sense: both ID and Measurement are the same for both observation.  Hence you merge both observations to both observations, which is what you get.

Comment: Perhaps just `cbind(df1, df2)` will do?

Comment: @Sharath I just ran your code above (with `x1` and `y1` in `foverlaps`) and didn't get any errors - perhaps you have an old `data.table` version or are doing smth different?

Comment: btw I only came back to this accidentally, so please ping me using @eddi if you want a response